# text css background like if it was done by hand

Tags: css, text, background

I want to style html text with css like in this picture:

[image]

I was googling for an hour for css that does that but nothing.

Is it done with:

1. css3?
2. background image with repeat-x?

thank you for any help!

Comment: could you provide the link where you saw this?

Answer (score 2):

its looks like its a image used as background

you can do this by repeating the image

Answer (score 0):

Should be no big deal. Just give an *inline* element a fitting background image. A tiling one or one as long as your maximum line length.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

step : Put the text in a span that u want to apply the background

```
<span class="bgColor">Your text is here </span>

<style>
.bgColor {
    display: inline;
    font: bold 14px/18px arial;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 1px 0 1px 0;
    white-space: pre-line; /* Not understood by IE, use manual br for IE */
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the `<mark>` tag in HTML5.

Comment: its might be but is it possible that the user can create the background like that without image since you can see that it looks like the image

Answer (score 0):

You may enclose the text in <span> the one which is been highlighted as show in your design sample.
Background patterns are different, so you use 4 images for the four span elements, to style in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not so clear to me.

But if you use this, may resolve your problem

```
<style type="text/css">
.highlight { background-color:#c9e665 !important; }
</style>

Your <span class="highlight">text goes</span> here.
```

Comment: thx for your response, but i'm talking about hand effect! limits of background are like if it was done with a color pen and by hand!